# How to sort Shape keys by "a to z" in blender 2.8?

Tags: python, add-on, shape-keys

In 2.79,we could sort them by "a to z".But in 2.8, the function has disappeared.
Is there any addons or python scripts?

Comment: you can find it by clicking an icon "⊕" at the bottom of the shape key tab.

Comment: oh yes you're right, it's actually an arrow, not a +

Comment: What else? Isn't [that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/149834/31447) what you've searched for? @ぬらとん Otherwise please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in this area, but something along the lines of this script, executed on the current active object, in Object Mode ?

```
import bpy


ob = bpy.context.object
skeys = ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks 

skey_names = sorted(skeys.keys(), key=lambda v: v.upper())

for name in skey_names:
    idx = skeys.keys().index(name)
    ob.active_shape_key_index = idx
    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_move(type='BOTTOM')
```

which works, but any edits to improve style are welcome. I can't help thinking I've handled that list in a clunky way.

EDIT in response to @lemon's comment:

The reason I thought this was clunky was that I thought there was no guarantee of the order of keys in a Python dictionary. But 1... [that's not true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007169/11419356), and 2... I don't think it matters anyway.

- `skey_names` is just an independent alphabetically sorted list of strings; a snapshot of the dict-keys of the  [`bpy_prop_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html#bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection) of shape keys. We are assuming the contents of original property-dictionary will not be modified before the loop terminates, but assume nothing about order .

For each of those sorted names, **in order** ...

- ... the ordinary Python dictionary call of `.index(str)` returns its position in the current state of the original property-dictionary, wherever it is ...
- .. to be used to set the read/write `.active_shape_key_index` to make the shape key labeled by it active...
- ... so the context-sensitive `bpy.ops.object.shape_key_move` can send it to the bottom of the list, (preserving the order of the other items).

Sending each item to the bottom of the list in alphabetical order results in an alphabetically-sorted list

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked well.

Comment: Yes it is!! But am totally unable to understand how! I've print( name, idx ) and tried to do it manually but still don't get it. Could you explain, please?

Comment: @lemon hope the edit helps .. I'm still feeling my way around Python, let alone the API, so I'm afraid my terminology might not be very clear.. what with shape-keys, key-keys, dictionary-keys..  8\

Comment: @RobinBetts, thanks... had just mingled 'down' and 'bottom'... my bad!

Answer (score 1):

We still have *sort by name* option (AZ), it's hidden by default though. Just roll out the search options:

[image]